# How to create event handler for AvalonEdit (ICSharpCode) Text Editor control?

Tags: c#, avalonedit

I am creating event handlers for on keypress and on caret position changed.

The "KeyDown" event works fine, but the code for "PositionChanged" fails with the error:

> No overload for 'TextEditor_PositionChanged' matches delegate.

```
textEditor.ActiveTextAreaControl.TextArea.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.TextEditor_KeyDown);
textEditor.ActiveTextAreaControl.TextArea.Caret.PositionChanged += new EventHandler(this.TextEditor_PositionChanged);

private void TextEditor_PositionChanged()
{
    StatusLine.Text = textEditor.ActiveTextAreaControl.Caret.Position.ToString();

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the method needs to match the signature expected by the delegate. `private void TextEditor_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: I understand now, that's perfect, thanks.